# Let $K_1, K_2, \ldots, K_N$ be compact subsets of the metric space $(X,d)$. Prove the $\bigcap K_i$ and $\bigcup K_i$ are compact.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, sequences-and-series

Let $K_1, K_2, \ldots, K_N$ be compact subsets of the metric space $(X,d)$. Prove the $\bigcap K_i$ and $\bigcup K_i$ are compact.

It should be noted that in my textbook only the definition of compactness is given:

> Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. A subset $K \subseteq X$ is compact when every point sequence in $K$ has a convergent subsequence with limit in $K$.

I've tried to look up some answers, but they all use Heine-Borel or some other results, that I'm not aware of yet.

I know $\bigcap K_i$ is a subset of $K_i$. Hence if we have a point sequence $\{a_n\}$ in $\bigcap K_i$ it must be a point sequence in $K_i$. So for each $K_i$ there exists $n_{i_1} < n_{i_2}, \ldots $ such that the subsequence of $\{a_n\}$ converge with limit in $K_i$. How can I use this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a first subsequence in $\cap K_i$ that converges with limit $a$ in $K_1$. That subsequence is also inside $K_2$, so a sub-subsequence must converge with limit in $K_2$, etc. You can continue doing this and argue that the limit is unique to conclude $a\in \cap K_i$.

For the union case, notice that a sequence in $\cup K_i$ must have an infinite number of terms belonging to $K_j$ for some $j$. You can then extract a subsequence belonging entirely to $K_j$ out of those terms. I'm sure you can continue from here.

Comment: Thank you, I see it is the idea from the proof of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem.

Answer (score 2):

$K_1$ gives you a convergent subsequence of $a_n$, let's call it $b_k$. Because $b_k$ is convergent, it has a limit, $b$. Prove that this limit lies in $K_i$ for all $i$.

Hint: Since $b_k$ is a sequence in $K_i$, it has a convergent subsequence with a limit in $K_i$. Can you prove that this limit equals $b$?